# Symfo3 convert to pdf

Tags: symfony, pdf

I need to convert a page to html, my site is on symfony3

i shearched into php and symfony documentation and i didn t find anything

here is the view i want to convert :

```
<div class="container cardResult">
<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header text-center">CLIENT</div>
            <div class="card-body card_result">
                <p class="card-text">{{ app.session.get('civilStatus').civility }} {{ app.session.get('civilStatus').lastName }} {{ app.session.get('civilStatus').firstName }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{ app.session.get('civilStatus').customerAddress }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{ app.session.get('civilStatus').CustomerZipCode }} {{ app.session.get('civilStatus').customerCity }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header text-center">FISCALITÉ</div>
            <div class="card-body card_result">
                <p class="card-text">Situation familiale : {{ app.session.get('taxation').familySituation }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Nombre d'enfants : {{ app.session.get('taxation').numberOfChildren }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Nombre de parts fiscales
                    : {{ app.session.get('taxation').numberOfTaxShares|number_format(1, ',', ' ') }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Salaire déclaré
                    : {{ app.session.get('taxation').salaryDeclared|number_format(2, ',', ' ') }} €</p>
                <p class="card-text">Revenu foncier
                    : {{ app.session.get('taxation').landIncomes|number_format(0, ',', ' ') }} €</p>
                <p class="card-text">BIC : {{ app.session.get('taxation').bic }} €</p>
                <p class="card-text">BNC : {{ app.session.get('taxation').bnc }} €</p>
                <p class="card-text">BA : {{ app.session.get('taxation').ba }} €</p>
                <p class="card-text">Impôts sur le revenu : {{ app.session.get('taxation').incomeTax }} €</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time google your problem before asking ...
You could install wkhtmltopdf (open ource tool) (install it in dev and production env) + use [knpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle), it works well on Symfony 3

Comment: there is still one issue with knpsnappy . If there is any image,it will not get in export